# JOURNALRECORDPROC determine key pressed

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook, journal

Here is the prototype of my function:

`LRESULT CALLBACK JournalRecoProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`
`{`

`}`

How can I check inside, if there was ENTER or mouse button clicked ?
I guess lParam should be used, but I couldn't find how.

Comment: According to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx EVENTMSG::message from WM_KEYFIRST to WM_KEYLAST - keyboard, otherwise something else.

Comment: Journal hooks are *very* hard to get going these days, you almost always get an access denied error when trying to set the hook.  Key loggers are not very popular with users.  Bypassing UIPI is required, that requires a manifest, a certificate and the correct install location.  Don't assume that what you see working on XP is going to reproduce well on other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> If the hook procedure returns a message in the range **WM_KEYFIRST** to
>   **WM_KEYLAST**, the following conditions apply:
>
> - The **paramL** member of the **EVENTMSG** structure specifies the virtual key code of the key that was pressed.
> - The **paramH** member of the **EVENTMSG** structure specifies the scan code.
> - There's no way to specify a repeat count. The event is always taken to represent one key event.

So, you would access it something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK JournalPlaybackProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // ... blah blah ...

    if (code == HC_GETNEXT)
    {
        // examine eventmsg
        EVENTMSG *pEvent = (EVENTMSG*)lParam;

        // keypress
        if (pEvent->message >= WM_KEYFIRST &&
            pEvent->message <= WM_KEYLAST)
        {
            // decode key press
            unsigned int uVirtualKeyCode = pEvent->paramL;
            unsigned int uScanCode = pEvent->paramH;

            // do your conditional checks here
            if (uVirtualKeyCode == VK_ENTER)
            {
                // Enter key was pressed
            }
        }
        else if (pEvent->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            // left mouse click
        }
        else // ... add checks for other messages ....
    }

    // ... blah blah ...
}
```

Comment: @edit, the thing wrong here is `uVirtualKeyCode == VK_ENTER` we need `LOBYTE(uVirtualKeyCode == VK_ENTER)`